# Subscribe to 2 topics

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If lets say i have a program to subscribe both topic A and B.
Topic A  give me an integer of 5
and B give me an integer of 10.
Now i want to add them up to give me 15.

My problem is i do not know how link both values such that they can be added since the values  are in their own callback functions.

- side note: i am using python language. appreciate if someone can write a simple program as reference or guiding me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327579/subscribe-to-2-topics/) by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will probably want to have your callbacks as members of a class. When a callback is called, you will then store the data from the callback as data in the class. This way all methods of the class has access to that data.
Please notice that you need to guard data from threading issues since the rospy callbacks can happen concurrently.

Walk through the basic tutorials related to rospy if you have not already. It is time well spent.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0